# Did the influence of women in the Paris Commune affect future women's movements?

Tags: 19th-century, france, women

There is a lot of evidence that shows that women played an instrumental role in the Paris Commune of 1871 following the Franco-Prussian War of 1870-1871. However, I do not seem to find any information on the influence that these 'communardes' had on future women movements.

I have briefly heard that the use of posters or 'affiches' in the Commune influenced the use of posters during the suffragette movements. But I really would like to find evidence on the legacy, if any, that these women of the Paris Commune had on the feminist movements of the 20th century.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)If there is a lot of evidence, it should be easy to cite some, which will help others who want to research the topic.

Comment: As you haven't given the extent of your work to date, it's rather hard to guide you. If you have not done an extensive research and want to start at the start, you could read a biography of the best known of these women: Louise Michel. The one in Wikipedia in French is better than the one in English. You can use automatic translation if needed. In it, you will encounter other "pétroleuses" as they were called. It should help you get a basis for your research. Also in both English and French Wikipedia, there is a Legacy section which could be of help.